# How to create an object by referring to a property

Tags: java, methods

I want to create an object of a class by referring to its object, I think. I've been able to make it in C# but in Java it wont work. This is what I want to do:

```
controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson() = new Person(student.getIdNumber(), student.getName(), student.getAddress(), student.getTel());
```

But I get a error message saying:The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

How can I fix the problem? I've tried like doing like this:

```
register.AddStudent(controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson());
```

and then

```
System.out.println("Show info: " + controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson());
```

and the output I get is : Person@7cd0a5d9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have the Property syntax that c# does.  you have to use a setter.

```
controller.getDal().getStudentData().setPerson(
    new Person(/*blah blah blah*/)
);
```

if you control whatever type `getStudentData` returns, than you might have to make one.

```
public void setPerson(Person newPerson)
{
    this.person = newPerson;
}
```

Comment: I've done the setter before making this code. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Eskipo That's **exactly** what c# properties do behind the scenes.  It's just a different syntax

Comment: Okay I'll try to do that and I'll be back soon :)

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are trying to set a new person using a get method.  You cannot set an object to a function.  You are on the right track with your code:

```
register.AddStudent(controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson());
```

I do wonder however if in your code that a student and a person are the same thing.  You did not provide enough code for me to test and to give you an guaranteed answer, but I would assumg that your code should be more like this:

```
register.AddStudent(controller.getDal().getStudent());
```

This way you are getting the student and then adding the student.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you should really be looking into set methods such as something like:

```
Person p = controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson();
p.setIdNumber = 0011559966
p.setAddress('123 C St');
```

Or even something along the lines of:

```
register.AddStudent(new Student("Billy", "Crystal", "123 C st"));
```

Anyway, if you had more code, I would be able to help you more, but that is the best I can think of without any real context

Comment: I tried doing as you said but didn't work. There i an aggregate relationship between Person, which is base class and Student which is subclass. I'll show more code.

Comment: @Eskipo That's great.  Any chance my code was the proper answer?  Upvotes and correct answer marking for reputation would be helpful to me :)

Comment: oconnecp it indeed was. But Sam I Am's was more "spot on". But if I could give many accepted answers you would get one. :) But I vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

About:

```
System.out.println("Show info: " + controller.getDal().getStudentData().getPerson());
```

You must override the `toString()` method inside the `Person` class to the fields or string representation you want to see upon printing.

An example could be:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Name: " + this.getName() + " Id Num: " + this.getIdNumber();
}
```

Comment: Thank you gtgaxiola this actually was one of the things that solved my problem.